# go言語でSVDを行いたい

Tags: go

GO言語を使って、
ある行列に対して、
Singular Value Decomposition(SVD)を行い、Unitary matrix（UやVtなど）の行列を計算したいです。

簡単なコードを書きましたので、それを示した後に、質問をさせていただきます。

```
package main

import (
    // "gonum.org/v1/gonum/blas/blas64"
    // "gonum.org/v1/gonum/lapack"
    // "gonum.org/v1/gonum/lapack/lapack64"
    "gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat"
  "fmt"

)

func main() {
  v1 := []float64{3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, -2.0};
  a := mat.NewDense(2, 3, v1)

  svd := new(mat.SVD)
  svd.Factorize(a, mat.SVDFull)
  a.UFromSVD(svd) //<-ここが問題です。
}
```

[ここのサイト](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/tree/master/mat)を参考にSVDのテストを行っております。
この中に、svd.goがあります。その中で、「Factorize」「UFromSVD」や「VFromSVD」があります。
上記のコードでは、行列aを作成した後、Factorize(SVDFullのオプション)で計算をしています。最後の行では、U行列を取り出すことを試みていますが、そこで問題が発生しています。

サイトには

```
func (m *Dense) UFromSVD(svd *SVD)
```

とありますので、それを参考に上記のようなコード（a.UFromSVD(svd)）を書きました。
しかし、エラーメッセージが以下のようです。

```
a.UFromSVD undefined (type *mat.Dense has no field or method UFromSVD)
```

他のfunction（Kind, Cond）などは正常に動くことを確認しています。
エラーに「method UFromSVDがない」とのことなので、UFromSVDの使い方が間違っているとおもいますが、修正の仕方が分からず、どつぼにハマっている状態です。

ここであれば、ご教授をしていただけないかと思い、質問を投稿しました。
よろしくお願いします。

ちなみに使っているスペックは
OS: Ubuntu, Go: 1.8.3です。

Comment: gonumの[svd.go](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/blob/aad36a059009dc681b68a7d9fbdcadd09c9db798/mat/svd.go)にも[gonum/gonum自体](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/search?q=UFromSVD)にも`UFromSVD`というのは無いように見えます。何を参考にされてらっしゃいますか？

Comment: [gonum/svd.go at master · gonum/gonum](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/blob/master/mat/svd.go#L190)に `UTo()` というメソッドがあり、コメントや処理内容を見ると `UFromSVD()` メソッドと同等の様に見えます。`UTo()` を使う場合は、`b := &mat.Dense{}` として、`svd.Uto(b)` として U行列を取り出す様です。

Comment: [commit log](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/commit/15641d34f4aaebb4767dbc959f3e7b1aaaa07609#diff-df713b94302908c2d7bd7b69f1ef3d8a) を見ると、やはりメソッド名が変更になっていますね。

Comment: nekketsuuu様、metropolis様、ご指摘の通り、どうやら自分で調べた時には、古いversionのsvdを見ていました。metropolis様が示していただいたUTo()でうまく動くことが確認出来ました。ありがとうございました。